# Should I use an empty string instead of NULL when checking for unique?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm still relatively new to database design, and I'm making a table with SQLite.  I thought I was taught that it's best to use NULL in place of empty strings, so that's what I've been doing.  I'm building an address table with the line:

```
CREATE TABLE addresses (
addressID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
officeName TEXT,
address TEXT NOT NULL CHECK(address<>''),
UNIQUE (officeName, address)
```

And adding addresses to the database (through PHP PDO) using the line

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO addresses (officeName,address) VALUES (?,?)
```

That line should check to see if the officeName/address is already in the database, and ignore it if it is, or add it if it isn't.  "Address" is always a non-null string, but sometimes the officeName is blank.  And if I make it NULL, it keeps getting added as if each NULL was distinct (it works fine if it's just an empty string).  I did find [this article](http://www.sqlite.org/nulls.html) saying that yes, NULLs are treated as distinct in a unique column.  That now makes me wonder… should I always just use an empty string instead of NULL?  Is there ever a case where it's "best practice" to use NULL instead?  I thought it was always best practice, but now I'm thinking it might never be best practice.

Comment: Whether to use NULL or an empty string is a slightly controversial topic. See [this question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/32578/sql-empty-string-vs-null-value).

Comment: Ooh, I love stirrin' up a controversy!

Answer (score 2):

`NULL` and the empty string are semantically *different*, just as `NULL` and `0` are semantically different.

`NULL` means "no value". In your case, that would be "no address".

Empty string is string string value of zero length. In your case, that would be an address that is the empty string.

**Whether or not to use `NULL` or the empty string depends on the semantics of the situation, just like the decision of whether to use `NULL` or `0`.**

However, `NULL`s are a bit of a mess when it comes to comparison, `IN`, indexes, `DISTINCT`, and `GROUP BY`. [Everyone seems to do things a little differently](http://www.sqlite.org/nulls.html) (FYI, this link doesn't cover SQL Server, which does it yet another way), so unfortunately, compromises are often made to accommodate particular desired behavior, depending on the DBMS.

In your case, you will have to use empty strings if you want to use the SQLite functionality you are interested in.

> SQLite was originally coded in such a way that [NULLs are never distinct]. But the experiments run
>   on other SQL engines showed that none of them worked this way. So
>   SQLite was modified to work the same as Oracle, PostgreSQL, and DB2.
>   This involved making NULLs indistinct for the purposes of the SELECT
>   DISTINCT statement and for the UNION operator in a SELECT. NULLs are
>   still distinct in a UNIQUE column. This seems somewhat arbitrary, but
>   the desire to be compatible with other engines outweighed that
>   objection.

Know, however, that `INSERT OR IGNORE` is unique to SQLite; for no other DBMS would you be asking about using that statement.

Best practice is to base your decision on what you mean: no value, or the value with no characters. (Of course, you may always choose to forgo best practice for your own personal reasons.)

Comment: I'm not 100% my question was conveyed correctly to you.  Every row in the listing has an address (which is the street address), but not all of them have an officeName.  If I use NULL, it will then add dozens of identical rows if I add an address that's already there, but doesn't have an office name, because it treats each NULL entry as unique.  Does that make sense?

Comment: When you say "In your case, you will have to use NULLs if you want to use the SQLite functionality you are interested in.", you mean "have to use empty strings, not NULLs", right?

Comment: @DanGoodspeed, yes, that was a typo. Thanks for catching it.